# Bind9 name server cannot resolves local domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-14.04, internal-dns

I tried to set up bind DNS in Ubuntu.

I have two machines (VMware):

machine A is client:

```
IP: 192.168.1.1  (host-only)
hostname: example.com
```

machine B is DNS Server:

```
IP: 192.168.1.2 (host-only)
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};
//reverse zone
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

/etc/bind/db.example.com:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com.        root.example.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.1
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
```

/etc/bind/db.192:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. root.example.com. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example.com.
1       IN      PTR     example.com.
```

When i use nslookup in client:

```
nslookup example.com
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Name:   example.com
Address: 192.168.1.1

nslookup 192.168.1.1
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

** server can't find 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Can you fix it?

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything obvious, is bind named logging anything? i.e. do you get confirmation that the zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa is loaded?

Comment: I am beginner, i don't sure

Answer (score -1):

First of all you state in your named.conf.local that your zone is `example.com`. So B hostname cannot be `example.com`. It could be `some-hostname` on `example.com` like `foo.example.com` but not `example.com` since it implies that your zone is `com` and B's hostname is `example` which is not consistent with the configuration you provided.

There is an error in`/etc/bind/db.example.com`.

```
@       IN      NS      example.com.
```

This lines is used to specify domain name server. Here you just said :

```
@(expand to example.com)'s name server is `example.com`
```

which should be

```
@       IN     NS      "B's hostname".example.com
```

Then you specify the A records related to the NS records (i.e your nameserver IP adress) :

```
hostname       IN      A       192.168.1.1
               IN      AAAA    ::1
```

But this is still bad configuration. You said before that your nameserver is B with IP 192.168.1.2 right ? So the statement above should be

```
hostname       IN      A       192.168.1.2
```

This is the same for the SOA records in `db.example.com`:

`@       IN      SOA     example.com.        root.example.com.`

should be :

```
@       IN      SOA     "B's hostname".example.com.        root.example.com.
```

SOA records in `db.192` should be exactly the same as `db.example.com`, no needs to write `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`.

Then again your NS and PTR records aren't correct, they should be :

```
@       IN      NS      "B's hostname".example.com.
2       IN      PTR     "B's hostname".example.com.
```

I hope I didn't miss something but for last piece of advice Bind9 is packaged with two scripts `named-checkzone` and `named-checkconf`. The former can check zone file (i.e `db.192` and `db.example.com`) and the latter can check Bind9 configuration (i.e `named.conf.local`).

If you are interested in understand better how Bind9 (and dns) you should have a look at [Zytrax Pro DNS and Bind](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch1/) which explain very well configuration options with plenty of examples.

Comment: example.com is name's machine 1, why dns have to "B's hostname".example.com. instead of B's hostname". ?

Comment: And I want nslookup 192.168.1.1, why fix 1 to 2 ?

Comment: When i fix db.example.com as way of you, nslookup example.com from machine A get error ** server can't find example.com: SERVFAIL

Comment: You have to define a domain name whose records will be handled by a name server. Say you choose `example.com` the nameserver will be a machine on this domain (i.e `WhateEverYouNameIt.example.com`). If machine1 name is example.com it implies that you're trying to set-up a machine named `example` on domain `com` which is not consistent with your `named.conf.local` which states `example.com`. Do you understand better ? Have you check the commands I recommended you ?

Comment: I think it would be great if you could edit your question to show what domain you are trying to configure.

Comment: How way to show domain work?

Comment: This is a completely different question I gave you a link that explain things in details like how DNS protocol works and how to configure bind.